# POST requests sometimes getting cut off on Amazon EC2 server, causing Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, post, iis

I have an ASP.NET 4.7.2 WebForms project that uses both standard postbacks with viewstate and AJAX requests using JSON data.  It is hosted on Amazon Web Services EC2 using a load balancer to split requests between 2 IIS servers. (The sessions are set to sticky so it shouldn't be switching servers partway through the session.) Most of the time these requests work fine.  I'm servicing many thousands of requests per day that have no problems.

Unfortunately not all the requests work correctly.  I'm getting about 200 requests per day that throw an error. Either "Invalid postback or callback argument" for the requests with a viewstate or "Unterminated string passed in" for the JSON ones.  When this happens, my error logger records the POST parameters for the request and I can see that the request was cut-off and the entire viewstate or JSON request didn't come through. (The JSON requests include a file base64 encoded and only part of it comes through.)

If the user retries the request it seems to work, but they shouldn't have to.  These are not spam bots because the entire site is behind a login screen and the values I'm seeing in the incomplete requests are real valid data... just not all of it.

I'm not sure how to track down this problem as it seems intermittent, and as far as I can tell ASP.NET is doing the right thing saying the data is invalid... it is invalid because it's incomplete.  On the other hand I'm using pretty standard services with AWS and IIS running an ASP.NET site and if there was a bug in any of those I'd expect it would have been fixed a long time ago or people wouldn't be using them.

Comment: It sounds just like some bandwith has been reached at that time.  Have you monitored the application pool at that time including concurrent connections? Besides, could you capture any first chance exception when you reproduce this issue?

Comment: I'm capturing exceptions in Global.Application_Error.  That's where I'm seeing the Invalid Postback from.

Comment: Looking at the Windows Event Viewer under Application for the given time I'm seeing "An unhandled exception has occurred." and the details also say "Invalid postback or callback argument".  I'm not seeing any other exceptions at the same time in that view

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "monitored the application pool" what would I need to do for this?  I think I'm capturing all exceptions so the first chance exception would be the invalid postback... but again I'm not sure what you mean by this

Comment: I think you'd better deep analyze the crash dump file to find the inner exception. Because its still uncertain why IIS return this exception.Besides, have you monitored the server load? DId you see any abnormal behavior when your post return invalid postback? Like long time taken or high concurrent requests number?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by deep analyze the crash dump file? I've scrolled through the entire textbox in the event viewer and there is no inner exception there.  In my Global.Application_Error it starts with System.Web.HttpUnhandledException with the message of "Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown." then the inner exception is the System.ArgumentException with the message "Invalid postback or callback argument."